# How to stop Ubuntu 20.04 from suspending when the screen blanks?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, suspend

I swear, next upgrade(if I live that long) I am going to reformat my hard drive and load Ubuntu from scratch. It will be less of a hassle.
Specifically I updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Something that struck me as strange is that the installer didn't ask me what desktop to install. Last time it did. I was using the Unity desktop at the time, and it is still more or less working.
There were a couple problems in your face, like no sound and no volume control on the top bar, even after I got the sound working again, but those problems are now resolved.
The big problem is this: whenever the screen blanks, the computer also suspends(I think this is the right term). The WIFI and Bluetooth turn off, and any program running suspends, Upon coming out of suspension the programs running try to continue, but there is always an error.
So my question is, how do I make the computer stop suspending when the screen blanks? I used to run programs, such as Handbrake even overnight. The screen blanking did not bother it at all.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you already disabled suspend under system settings?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to have any effect.